# Can an HTTP connection be passed from IIS/ASP.NET to another application or service?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, websocket

I'm looking into building an ASP.NET MVC application that exposes (other than the usual HTML pages) JSON and XML REST services, as well as [Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets).

In a perfect world, I would be able to use the same URLs for the Web Sockets interface as I do for the other services (and determine which data to return by what the user agent requests) but, knowing that IIS wasn't built for persistent connections, I need to know if there's a way that I can accept (and possibly even handshake) the Web Sockets connection and then pass the connection off to another service running on the server.

**I do have a workaround in mind if this isn't possible** that basically involves using ASP.NET to check for the Web Sockets connection upgrade headers, and responding with a `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` that points to a different host that has my Web Sockets service configured to directly listen to the appopriate endpoint(s).

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question; I'm still dying to see an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the claim that "IIS wasn't built for persistent connections"-- persistent connections are the default for HTTP/1.1, and IIS fully supports them. More generally, a TCP/IP socket can be passed to a child process, but generally cannot be passed to a non-child process.

Comment: I may have been unclear about what I meant by "persistent connections;" as far as HTTP is concerned, a persistent connection is one that can be open as long as the user agent is retrieving pages/content during a request. This will still only last a few seconds; I'm talking about a connection that could last for several minutes, moving data back and forth between the server and the user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I completely understand your goal, I believe you can use the IIS7/7.5 Application Request Routing module to accomplish this.

Here's a quick reference: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/489/using-the-application-request-routing-module/

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than 302 responses you could use ISAPI_rewrite to direct to an appropriate endpoint (and manipulate the HTTP header to get it there)

http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/

Otherwise no, IIS cannot natively pass off an HTTP connection. The current MSFT method is to use a 302 or something else that is intercepting the raw socket and performing header manipulation prior to sending to IIS (or whatever other application)

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that this would be a better question to ask Microsoft than to ask us. Web Sockets is new technology, and rather than looking for a hack, you might want to ask Microsoft how they plan to support it. IIS is their software. Poke around on http://iis.net (maybe in http://forums.iis.net) and see what you learn.

Comment: While Microsoft may be planning Web Socket support in IIS futures, I'm looking for a broader answer simply about passing HTTP connections to any external process.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use a unique Session ID that is associated with the Http Session.  From the description, it seems like you might want to scope this to a single HttpApplication instance, but this is not necessary (you may also persist a session across many application instances).  Anyway, this session ID needs to be attached somehow to each Http Request (either with a cookie, querystring, static variable with the HttpApplication instance, form data).  Then you persist the identifying information about the Http session somewhere with the ID.

This identifying information may vary depending on your needs but could entail the entire http request or just some stripped down representation that serves your particular purpose.

Using this SessionID somewhere in the Http request allows you to restore whatever information you need to call and interact with the appropriate services.  The instances of the services may also need to be scoped to the session as well.

Basically, what I am suggesting is that you **NOT** directly pass the Http connection to an external process, but instead pass the necessary data to the external process, and allow create a mechanism for sending callback data.   I think looking into the mediator pattern may be helpful for you in understanding what I mean here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern .  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. However, it doesn't look like it takes IIS out of the loop, which is my primary concern.

Comment: From your description, I do not see how IIS needs to do anything more complicated than a standard deployment.  I have successfully created RESTful ASP.NET MVC JSON/XML applications using this technique.  Perhaps, if you gave a little bit more specific explanation of your intentions I could help you more.